# Change application-specific password for Google Chrome

Tags: google-chrome

I have just set up Chrome with my Google Account, and an application-specific password has been assigned to me... this password is long, and I need to enter it quite often...

Does anyone know how to change it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot change application passwords, they can be only generated and revoked.

However, you *should not* need to enter it more than once – at least not within Chrome itself; the program should remember it for as long as necessary. If it does not, you are likely using a very nonstandard configuration.